# SPARQL Update: Underscore not allowed in language tag

Tags: sparql, rdf, blazegraph

I am trying to insert data into blazegraph using the 'Update' tab of blazegraph workbench. Below is a sample code snippet:

```
INSERT DATA
{
  ns:MyNode ns:hasValue "MyValue"@en_us
}
```

I am specifying language tag with @ symbol. However, it throws following exception:

> org.openrdf.query.MalformedQueryException: Lexical error at line 8,
>   column 49.  Encountered: "u" (117), after : "_"

It seems that it does not allow an underscore as part of language tag. If try just with 'en' it works fine.

Why is that so? Is underscore a special character here? If so, what is the way to escape it?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for language tags is defined by an RFC, now revised in [RFC5646](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646). Registration of language tags is controlled by IANA.

Subtags are separated by "`-`"; only `A-Z,0-9` are legal in subtags.

When adopted for RDF syntaxes (N3, SPARQL, Turtle etc), the grammar pattern  adopted was a compromise syntax that weakly matches the RFC.  `'@' [a-zA-Z]+ ('-' [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` without taking all the details. The subtag separator is "`-`". "`_`" is not allowed in a language tag.